# Why is my python console running as 32-bit?

Tags: python, windows-10, 64-bit, version

I double checked Pycharm installation and it is a 64-bit. There is only one.
I double checked Python version and it is a 64-bit (installed in C:\Python37-64). There is only one.

Why is my Python console reading the following?!?

```
Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
```

How do I go about moving to 64-bit?

Thanks.

edit1

```
import platform
print(platform.architecture()[0])
```

returns 32-bit

Comment: What's the output of `where python` when run from the command line?

Comment: C:\Python37-64\python.exe

Comment: Why do you want to run 64 bit python?

Comment: having memory issues with reading large files with pandas

Comment: Can you run `import sys; print(sys.maxsize > 2**32)`? The output will be True if you are running 64 bit

Comment: Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul  8 2019, 19:29:22) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
import sys; print(sys.maxsize > 2**32)
False

Comment: Just thought about it but I do have an AMD Ryzen 5 2600X and not an Intel chip ... could that make sense?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it looks like my Ryzen is not compatible with Python 3.7.4.
After installing 3.7.2 in a new venv \o/

```
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```